# Include Jquery Parameter in Echo PHP with Row

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql

hello ive been trying to figure this out for days now.

What i want to do is echo a test and then create a button that copies the echoed text to the clipboard.

So what i want is that i have an SQL list, in that List there is an ID row i can pass to my echo in the paragraph, but when i try to do the same with the parameter the # seems to an issue.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<div>";
   echo "  <p id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['Message'] . "</p>";
   echo '<button onclick="copyToClipboard('. $row['Title'] . ')">Copy TEXT 2</button>';
   echo "  </div>";
}
```

Also it somehow generates the parameter but there is a blank space between 
(" #om2")".

- my SQL
- ID = OM2
- Title = "#OM2"
- Message = some3ohruihrgfijbfgbrfghrgjikbnhjergbnergbg

any help is greatly appreciated

Edit.

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<textarea>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  var html = $(element).html();
  html = html.replace(/<br>/g, "\n"); // or \r\n
  console.log(html);
  $temp.val(html).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}


</script>
```

with `echo '<button onclick=\"copyToClipboard(' . $row['Title'] . ')>Copy TEXT 2</button>';`

[Image!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB2SY.png)

Comment: You can use trim() to eliminate whitespaces..

Comment: i tried in on after the echo and before the row started, tried on the row it self.
Same issue

Comment: trim($row['Title']) ? can we see your copyToClipboard javascript function ?

Comment: added it on edit.

Comment: Maybe it's quote problem, I think you would like to have the param as a string?:

echo '<button onclick="copyToClipboard(\"' . $row['Title'] . '\")">Copy TEXT 2</button>';

Comment: echo '<button onclick=\"copyToClipboard(' . $row['Title'] . ')\">Copy TEXT 2</button>';   removed some of the quotes suggested above. the parameter now shows properly but i have this "onclick="\"copytoclupboard("OM2")\""

Comment: if i remove the 1st \ the space is back on the parameter, if i remove the 2nd one i get double quotes before the closing > removing the " at the end only leaves 1, which is fine, now the only thing in my way is the "\" after the onclick =

Comment: @CarlosReyes did you this? Please not the position of the two \" . echo '<button onclick="copyToClipboard(\"' . $row['Title'] . '\")">Copy TEXT 2</button>';

Comment: Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass `#OM2` as agument of the `copyToClipboard()` function...

There are some quotes missing to make it a string. Actually, `#OM2` isn't.

Try to add some `\'`:

```
echo '<button onclick="copyToClipboard(\''. $row['Title'] . '\')">Copy TEXT 2</button>';
```

That should work... But I would suggest a better alternative...
Use a class handle the click event, instead of an inline `onclick`.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<div>";
   echo "  <p id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['Message'] . "</p>";
   echo '<button class="copy">Copy TEXT 2</button>';
   echo "  </div>";
}
```

Then your clipboard copy script would simply be:

```
$(".copy").on("click",function(){
  var text = $(this).prev("p").html().replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
});
```

---

Here is a snippet ;)

```js
$(".copy").on("click",function(){
  var text = $(this).prev("p").html().replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p id="OM2">some3ohruihrgfijbfgbrfghrgjikbnhjergbnergbg</p>
  <button class="copy">Copy TEXT 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it, and nothing happens. click the button but it not copying it to the clipboard

Comment: @CarlosReyes You may need to wrap the JS provided in the infamous `$(document).ready(function() {` wrapper.

Comment: Holy jesus!!! WAIT

Moved my script below >.> the php tags seems to work

Comment: Good! Happy clipboarding ;)